# How can I make one string based on others two?

Tags: c, string

Im trying to make one mix string based on others two, for example, string1 = "Good Morning" and string2 = "Hello guys", So my script will output like that: "Good Hello Morning guys".

I have almost done it.. what i tried:

```
int main() {
  char frase1[99];
  char frase2[99];
  int i =0;
  char frase3[99];

  printf("Type a sentence: ");
  gets(frase1);
  printf("Type a sentence: ");
  gets(frase2);

  char * pch1;
  char * pch2;

  pch1 = strtok (frase1," ");
  pch2 = strtok (frase2," ");

  while (pch1) {
    strcat(frase3,pch1); 
    pch1 = strtok (NULL, " ");

    strcat(frase3,pch2); 
    pch2 = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  puts(frase3);
}
```

output: Example: frase1 = "Good morning"; frase2 = "Hey guys"; output: error

Comment: please be more specific about the problem you want help with. Under what conditions does your code produce undesired output, and what is the output in those cases? This will help people help you, and is good practice for reporting errors precisely.

Comment: There is no output, I got error ):

Comment: For future question consideration... saying "I got an error" is nearly useless, but saying "I got the following error: _insert pasted error message here_" is much more useful.

Comment: But my program does not show error, it just stop working..

Comment: Don't use `gets`, it's dangerous, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: I get erro when I change it ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char frase1[99];
    char frase2[100] = {' '};
    char frase3[sizeof(frase1)+sizeof(frase2)];

    printf("Type a sentence: ");
    scanf("%98[^\n]", frase1);
    printf("Type a sentence: ");
    scanf(" %98[^\n]", frase2+1);

    char *pch1, *pch2, *pch3;
    int len1, len2;

    pch1 = frase1;
    pch2 = frase2;
    pch3 = frase3;

    while (*pch1 || *pch2) {
        if(*pch1){
            sscanf(pch1, "%*s%n", &len1);
            memcpy(pch3, pch1, len1);
            pch1 += len1;
            pch3 += len1;
        }
        if(*pch2){
            sscanf(pch2, "%*s%n", &len2);
            memcpy(pch3, pch2, len2);
            pch2 += len2;
            pch3 += len2;
        }
    }
    *pch3 = '\0';
    puts(frase3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is quite simple:

1. `strtok` is not psychic and has no idea you wanted to resume the earlier token sequence, and not the one it labored on last.
2. It will only return `NULL` wen it cannot return a token, you test for that *too late*.

Take the replacement-function `strtok_s` (optional C99 `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1`) or `strtok_r` (POSIX), which is reentrant because it does not use any static internal storage.
If you can do neither, save the first sequence and then get the second one.

Next problem will be having a different number of tokens in both sentences.

The final problem you will run into (if `frase1` and `frase2` are long enough) is overflowing `frase3`: That should be at least as long as both combined.

Comment: I get error when I type strtok_2, isnt it from <string.h>?

Comment: So, how can I add it to my program? can you make it for me?? Im trying to do it.. but i cant

Comment: Added the define for C99 and another way. Try it.

Comment: Im still having errors when I try to write strtok_s .Can u write the full program please? I trying to make it for 5 hours

Comment: Be careful what you wish for, you may get it.